# Trigger to update all the Child records in the hierarchy based on parent record

Tags: apex, trigger, helper

I have a Cusotm object which is used to save assets. There is a Self lookup relationship field called "Parent Asset ID" on this object and using this relationship, we create a parent-child relationship between any two Asset Records.
i.e, an Asset record may have one or more Child Asset Records and sometimes an asset record may not have any Child Asset record and at the same time, an asset record which is child to a Parent asset can be a parent to other asset record.

My requirement is, I have two picklist fields called Asset Class and Operator. Whenever the Asset class pick-list value is set to "Plant" my logic has to look for the related "Operator" field value and update the same value on all its Child records which are in the hierarchy. I wrote the below trigger for it.

Trigger:

```
trigger createSummaryAsset on sm1e__smEquipment__c (before update, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore)
       asynchBatcher.HandleATTrigger(trigger.new);

    if(Trigger.isAfter)
       AssetTagHelper.updateChildRecords(Trigger.newMap);   
}
```

Helper Class:

```
public class AssetTagHelper{

    public static String PLANT = 'Plant';

    public static void updateChildRecords(Map<Id, sm1e__smEquipment__c> newMap){
        //sm1e__smEquipment__c oldAssetTag;
        List<sm1e__smEquipment__c> assetTagList = new List<sm1e__smEquipment__c>();
        Map<Id, sm1e__smEquipment__c> assetTagMap = new Map<Id, sm1e__smEquipment__c>();

        for(sm1e__smEquipment__c assetTag : newMap.values()){
           //oldAssetTag = (sm1e__smEquipment__c)System.Trigger.oldMap.get(assetTag.Id);           
           if(assetTag.sm1e__Asset_Class__c == PLANT && assetTag.sm1e__Parent__c != null){
              assetTagMap.put(assetTag.Id, assetTag); 
           }   
        }

        if(assetTagMap != null && !assetTagMap.isEmpty()){
            assetTagList = [SELECT Id, 
                                   Operator__c,
                                   sm1e__Parent__c 
                            FROM sm1e__smEquipment__c 
                            WHERE sm1e__Parent__c IN: assetTagMap.keySet()];

            for(sm1e__smEquipment__c assetTag : assetTagList){
                if(assetTagMap.containsKey(assetTag.sm1e__Parent__c))
                   assetTag.Operator__c = assetTagMap.get(assetTag.sm1e__Parent__c).Operator__c;
            }

            if(assetTagList != null && !assetTagList.isEmpty())
               update assetTagList;
        }   
    }
}
```

The above code is only updating the direct child Records but not all the child records in the hierarchy. i.e, if an asset record has Asset class as "Plant" and some value on the "operator" field, If this asset has 4 child assets and each child asset further has 4 Child records, then only the records which are child to parent Asset (asset record with Asset Class value as "plant") are updated but not asset records that are children to child asset records.

What has to be changed in the logic to solve this issue?

Comment: `assetTagMap != null` and `if(assetTagList != null && !assetTagList.isEmpty())` are not necessary, but wn't fix your problem.

Comment: @sfdcfox: so how can i fix this issue? Do you have any suggestions??